# GROUP BY, ORDER BY - How to make group by consider latest apperance of item

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query like this (Mysql 5.X, PHP - formatted for legibility)

```
$query ="
SELECT 
  p.p_pid, 
  p.p_name, 
  p.p_url 
FROM 
  activity a, 
  products p 
WHERE 
  a.a_uid= ".$uid_int." 
  AND a.a_pid > 0 
  AND p.p_pid = a.a_pid 
GROUP BY 
  a.a_pid 
ORDER BY 
  a.a_time DESC LIMIT 6
");
```

In general it should produce a unique list of the 6 latest products the user has seen.

The problem is that if the user has seen a product more than once. one of them in the last 6 activities and one of them before the latest 6 activities the query does not return the product. I assume that the (group by) does not leave  a_time with the latest time of apperance of the product.  How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ordering by MAX(a.a_time) ?

```
SELECT 
  p.p_pid, 
  p.p_name, 
  p.p_url 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN activity a on p.p_pid = a.a_pid 
WHERE 
  a.a_uid= ".$uid_int." 
GROUP BY 
  p_pid, p_name, p_url
ORDER BY 
  max(a.a_time) DESC 
  LIMIT 6
```

As a best practice, use GROUP BY on every column you use without an aggregate.  MySQL is one of the few databases that allow you to use a column that's not being grouped on. It'll give you a random column from the rows you selected.

Answer (score 1):

I sure hope that `$uid_int` variable is double checked for SQL injection.

```
$query ="
SELECT 
  MAX(p.p_pid)  p_pid, 
  MAX(p.p_name) p_name, 
  MAX(p.p_url)  p_url
FROM 
  activity a
  INNER JOIN products p ON p.p_pid = a.a_pid 
WHERE 
  a.a_uid= ".$uid_int." 
  AND a.a_pid > 0 
GROUP BY 
  a.a_pid 
ORDER BY 
  MAX(a.a_time) DESC 
LIMIT 6
");
```

Sometimes I wonder if it was a good design decision from MySQL to allow grouping without explicit aggregation...

Comment: Thanks!. why do I need MAX on p_name etc..? these are strings.

Comment: Wrote it like that first too, but a group by on a.a_pid is really a group on p.  So it seems he wants to group by product, and find the last 6 products with activity.

Comment: @Nir: These are *not* strings. These are *groups of* strings, grouped by a.a_pid. That's why you must use an aggregation function to pick one string of the group. Even though MySQL allows some sloppiness here and it even may seem convenient - not using an aggregation function where it was appropriate is what caused your problem.