# GROUP BY & ORDER BY - Ordering by a specific field

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I need to write a query which returns a list of unique 'classes' ordered by the most popular item in that class. Here's an example query:

```
SELECT items.title, items.popularity 
FROM items, classes 
WHERE class_id = classes.id 
GROUP BY class_id 
ORDER BY MAX(items.popularity) DESC
```

This query returns the correct class but the item it returns is the first that appears in the table rather than the most popular.

Similarly I have tried:

```
SELECT MAX(items.title), items.popularity 
FROM items, classes 
WHERE class_id = classes.id 
GROUP BY class_id 
ORDER BY MAX(items.popularity) DESC
```

And all variations - this just returns the most recent added and not the most popular.

I've read [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263883/using-order-and-group-with-mysql-to-get-the-highest-number-for-each-group) and [lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857007/group-by-order-by-how-to-make-group-by-consider-latest-apperance-of-item) of other answers.

I'm sure there's a simple answer, please help!

Comment: `ORDER BY MAX(items.popularity) DESC` doesn't even make sense to me... ORDER BY is supposed to order by a column, and MAX returns a single value from that column. Shouldn't it just be `ORDER BY popularity DESC` to get the item with the largest `popularity` at the top?

Comment: When you GROUP BY it seems to choose the oldest record to head the group ignoring the popularity all together. Using the MAX functions has been the answer for a lot of similar questions.

Comment: GROUP BY is usually used when doing analysis such as MAX, MIN, AVG, COUNT, etc... the "oldest" record shouldn't matter because usually, GROUP BY is used to summarize/aggregate numerous records into one or two records. I admit I'm not even sure what you meant by that statement, though it sounds a bit like you might be getting confused by ORDER BY and GROUP BY...

Comment: ...and I have another question: Why is `classes` included in this query? I don't see the reason in joining `items` to `classes` because you're not selecting anything from `classes`, and the join condition seems trivial, unless it's possible to have a `class_id` in `items` that *doesn't* exist in `classes`...

Comment: This is a very good point, the full query does need classes. However I should have removed this from the simplified example.

Answer (score 2):

You are not selecting anything from classes, so don't need that table:

```
select i.*
from (
    SELECT class_id, max(popularity) as MaxPopularity
    FROM items 
    GROUP BY class_id  
) ip
inner join items i on ip.class_id = i.class_id 
    and ip.MaxPopularity = i.popularity
```

Note: You may get duplicates if there is more than one item in a class with the same popularity.

Comment: I think a subquery might be the only answer - I've not got this to work but you're on the right lines.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is you should order the MAX(popularity) in descending order, try adding DESC at the end of the query.

Comment: Apologies, I've added DESC to the statements. It should've been included.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try it but I think it should work...

```
SELECT MAX(items.title), items.popularity 
FROM items, classes 
WHERE class_id = classes.id 
GROUP BY class_id 
ORDER BY items.popularity DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT items.title, items.popularity 
FROM items, classes 
WHERE class_id = classes.id 
ORDER BY items.popularity DESC
```

You shouldn't need the group by as you are already selecting a specific class in the where statement. Additionally, the DESC in the order by should take care of the order without the need for the MAX.